# Local resources (images/js/css) not showing in Virtual Host

Tags: apache, apache2, virtualhost, httpd.conf, nagios

I'm setting up a virtual host for `nagios` with Apache 2.4 using mod_proxy_fcgi to forawrd php requests to php-fpm.

I wonder if it's the `ProxyPassMatch` that is making all of the local resources including images,js,css won't load when I go to `200.000.00:22222/nagios/index.php`.

All of the resources are interpreted as `Content-Type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1` as shown in the response headers. They show `403 Forbidden error` and in the error log it shows `AH01630: client denied by server configuration`.

/etc/httpd/conf.d/nagio.conf:

```
Listen 22222

<VirtualHost *:22222>

    ServerName {IP}:22222

    AddType image/jpeg jpeg jpg jpe

    ScriptAlias /nagios/cgi-bin "/usr/local/nagios/sbin"

    DocumentRoot "/usr/local/nagios"

    <Directory "/usr/local/nagios/sbin">

      Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

      AllowOverride None

      Require all granted

    </Directory>

    <LocationMatch "/nagios/((.*\.php)(/.*)?)$">

       ProxyPassMatch "fcgi://localhost:9000/usr/local/nagios/share/$1"

    </LocationMatch>

    <Directory "/usr/local/nagios/share">

         Options None

         AllowOverride None

         Require all granted

    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a `<Directory /usr/local/nagios>` section that permits Apache to serve from that directory. Basically, you need one of these for every `Alias` or `DocumentRoot` that isn't under an existing one.

Usually you just need "`require all granted`" or "order deny,allow (2.2.x and older) in the `Directory` section -- but check the ones for your existing `DocumentRoot's`